# drupal 7 is trying to get js and css via https and this breaks the site

Tags: javascript, theming, ssl

For some reason, anonymous users see my site as broken, and I realised this happens because pages call js and css files with https. But I don't have ssl configured, so this breaks.

What could cause this issue? I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have secure pages module installed ?

Comment: Nope. I was checking my logs, and it seems yandex is accessing pages through https. This rewrites every url, including images to grab https, and Boost caches this page with https links...Not sure why yandex does this since I only have an insecure self signed cert installed which warns users...